# When my minecraft has TPS of 20, but low fps, what does that mean?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to profile my minecraft, since I only have around 10-15 FPS, despite, IMHO, having a fast enough computer.
Using TickProfiler, I can see that I get 20 TPS. I assume this means Entity ticks aren't slowing me down. Is that right? Does that mean my low fps is rendering related?

In a completely empty world, I get 60-80 FPS.

CPU: AMD FX 8150

GPU: Radeon HD 7800

Answer (score 4):

TPS and FPS is not related. If you're getting a low FPS, but max TPS, it might be because you need a better graphics card.

TPS is how many times certain things in the game updates. By default, Minecraft updates 20 times per second. Each update is called a tick. 
"Ticks Per Second"

You can have more TPS than FPS, but the game will still be updating 20 times a second. Or, you can have more FPS than TPS, your screen will just show an image of the game that isn't updated from the last image (frame). Not everything in the game follows the TPS, that's why you don't get capped at 20 FPS.

Comment: I updated the question with my CPU & GPU, does that change anything? Is that GPU known to not work well for minecraft? Or the CPU?

Comment: I can't find much information about your GPU, but judging from that series of GPUs, that should be able to handle Minecraft fine even at higher resolutions and settings.
Questions Galore: What resolution are you playing at? What are your in-game settings? Do you use shaders or mods? What other processes, if any, do you have open when you're playing Minecraft?

Comment: I play 1.7.10 Simply Magic modpack with Chromaticraft added. I also added Optifine, but it doesn't really help too much. I have the problem no matter what configuration I use (even reducing range to two chunks doesn't help much). Not sure about the resolution, where would I see that? Full-screen vs. windowed doesn't change much. Most of the time I have Chrome running, but closing that doesn't change much either (which would also be unexpected since I have 32GB RAM and the Bulldozer should be handling the multi-tasking fine).

Comment: Then it's probably Minecraft, because it doesn't seem you have a hardware bottleneck or anything. The only other thing I could think of that could be affecting your FPS would be your java arguments. Maybe test another game or something?  Oh BTW, you can check your screen resolution in the debug screen (Shift+F3)

Comment: Alright, I know I'm really late, if this question is even relevant anymore, but the only other thing I can think of is bad graphics drivers. Bad drivers could be causing a ton of lag, I've had my FPS cut to 1/5 when I installed bad drivers. I don't think it's your CPU's single-threaded performance since OptiFine makes Minecraft utilize multiple cores. Though, modded Minecraft is very CPU intensive, and I don't know if OptiFine will utilize all eight cores. If you want to reinstall or update your graphics driver, make sure you do a clean uninstall first before installing new drivers.